# XspDateTimeHelper and XspInputText

Tags: xpages

I am trying to build an JSF library control for XPages based on the examples by Keith Strickland.

http://xprentice.gbs.com/A55BAC/keithstric.nsf/default.xsp?documentId=82770C11FA7B9B21852579C100581766

I am trying to create a function which creates an InputBox control with an attached DatePicker control.

here is code that I have tried :

```
    XspInputText inputText = new XspInputText();
    inputText.setId("inputText1");

    DateTimeConverter converter = new DateTimeConverter();
    converter.setType("date");
    inputText.setConverter(converter);
    XspDateTimeHelper dateTimeHelper = new XspDateTimeHelper();

    dateTimeHelper.setId("dateTimeHelper1");
    inputText.getChildren().add(dateTimeHelper);
    inputText.setRendered(true);
    this.getChildren().add(inputText);
```

The InputText control is rendered but the Converter, Validator and DatePicker button are not rendered.

Hi the answer from Keith solved the problem but now I had an other. I have tryed to add the inputtext to an fromtable from the exlib. Without the formtable arround the "DateTimePicker" is rendered correctly, but with the Formtable it is only rendered as a textfield.

here is the complete code:

```
    public class Libcontrol extends UIComponentBase implements FacesComponent {

            private static final String RENDERER_TYPE = "de.chris.Libcontrol ";
            private static final String COMPONENT_FAMILY = "de.chris";

            public void CommonContactInfo() {
                    setRendererType(RENDERER_TYPE);
            }

            @Override
            public String getFamily() {
                    return COMPONENT_FAMILY;
            }



            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public void initBeforeContents(FacesContext arg0) throws FacesException {


                    UIFormTable table = new UIFormTable();
                    table.setId("mytable");
                    table.setDisableRowError(false);
                    table.setDisableErrorSummary(true);
                    table.setLabelPosition("left");

                    UIFormLayoutRow row = new UIFormLayoutRow();
                    row.setId("myrow");
                    row.setLabel("DATEROW");

                    XspInputText inputText = new XspInputText();
                    inputText.setId("inputText1");

                    DateTimeConverter converter = new DateTimeConverter();
                    converter.setType("date");
                    inputText.setConverter(converter);
                    XspDateTimeHelper dateTimeHelper = new XspDateTimeHelper();

                    dateTimeHelper.setId("dateTimeHelper1");
                    inputText.getChildren().add(dateTimeHelper);
                    inputText.setRendered(true);
                    this.getChildren().add(inputText);


                    row.getChildren().add(inputText);
                    table.getChildren().add(row);

                    this.getChildren().add(table);


            }

            public void buildContents(FacesContext arg0, FacesComponentBuilder arg1) throws FacesException {
            // Do Nothing
            }

            /**
            * This method must be present because we're implementing FacesComponent
            */
            public void initAfterContents(FacesContext arg0) throws FacesException {
            // Do nothing
            }
    }
```

I'm not sure where the problem is, any ideas?

Comment: What method are you putting this in?

Comment: Agree with Toby, what is the context of "this"? Also, I noticed you didn't set a dateStyle on your converter, valid values are default, short, medium and long. I would think if one isn't defined it should fallback to "default" but I don't know that for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, think I may have found your issue. On the XPage/Custom Control itself, set the properties for:

dojoParseOnLoad=true

dojoTheme=true

or, if you don't want to set those properties in your XPage/Custom Control you can do it in the renderer encodeBegin with the following lines somewhere before the call to super.encodeBegin():

```
//Here context = FacesContext or FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
UIViewRootEx rootEx = (UIViewRootEx) context.getViewRoot();
rootEx.setDojoParseOnLoad(true);
rootEx.setDojoTheme(true);
```

Comment: Tanks for help after adding dojoParseOnLoad=true dojoTheme=true all works fine